# Why do two methods that are logically identical not perform the same task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails application, I have two methods in my application controller. One of them authenticates users (i.e. checks if a user is logged in, and redirects them to login if not). The other performs the first half of that task (i.e. checks if a user is logged in).

When the check is complete, if a user is logged in, both of these methods supposedly set a `@current_user` variable to the user object for the user who is currently signed in, by using `User.find`.

The former:

```
protected
def authenticate_user
  if session[:user_id]
     # set current user object to @current_user object variable
    @current_user = User.find session[:user_id]
    return true
  else
    flash[:notice] = "You must log in first."
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
    redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'login')
    return false
  end
end
```

The latter:

```
def check_login_status
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user = User.find session[:user_id]
    return true
  end
end
```

As you can see, the logic for the first half of each of these methods is identical. However, `authenticate_user` correctly sets the `@current_user` variable; `check_login_status` doesn't set it at all (as in, the check in the layout file says `@current_user.nil? == true`.

This is the relevant part of the layout file:

```
<% if not @current_user.nil? %>
  Logged in as <%= @current_user.username %> —
  <a href="/logout">log out</a> —
  <a href="/dashboard">dashboard</a> —
  <a href="/contacts">contacts</a> —
  <a href="/help">help</a>
  <% if @current_user.is_admin %>
    — <a href="/admin">admin</a>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <a href="/login">log in</a> —
  <a href="/sign-up">sign up</a> —
  <a href="/help">help</a>
<% end %>
```

I get the second set of links shown, indicating that I'm logged out.

So, why does the latter not set the `@current_user` variable correctly? Does it have anything to do with the `protected` marking (though somehow I doubt it)?

Comment: Is the latter method actually being called? Maybe the problem is in the routes, not the controller.

Comment: @das-g yes, I've used them both with a `before_filter` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the most likely explanation is that `check_login_status` is not being called at all since both are logically equivalent. However both duplicate the same authentication logic!

If you insist on reinventing the authorization wheel (don't unless its for learning purposes) you should avoid spreading the authentication logic all over your controllers and views.

Instead you use a helper module to create a simple API for authentication. This module should be the only part of the app that knows how the user is stored in the session:

```
module AuthorizationHelper
  def current_user
     return nil unless session[:user_id]
     # conditional assignment so DB is only queried once!
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def sign_in!(user)
     reset_session
     session[:user_id] = user.id
     @current_user = user
  end

  def sign_out!(user)
     reset_session
     @current_user = nil
  end

  def signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end
end
```

Now we just include the helper in `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController
  include AuthorizationHelper
  # ...
end
```

We also want to ensure authorization in a resusable and extendable way. A good way to do this is by raising an exception and caching it with `rescue_from`.

Lets create our own error class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  class AuthorizationError < StandardError; end
end
```

Lets add a authorization method:

```
module authorizationHelper
  # ..
  def authorize!
    raise User::AuthorizationError unless signed_in?
  end
end
```

Now we can use this in our controllers:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize!
end
```

However its not very useful as it just causes the app to crash! Lets rescue the exception:

```
class ApplicationController
  include AuthorizationHelper
  rescue_from User::AuthorizationError, with: :deny_access

  def deny_access
    redirect_to(controller: 'sessions', action: 'login') and return
  end
end
```